# How to edit a literal to only one user in pyTelegramBotAPI (telebot)

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I have a question, how can I edit a global literal but to only one user? I mean, let's say a message, how can I edit the message for only one person without using the "if user.id == 111:", I am searching a way to do it exactly like, through the bot as admin, its in telebot, python

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try smoothing like this:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id == <userid>)

def <yourFuncName>(message):
    answer = 'Your changed text'
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id, text=answer)
```